# Maven The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly (install java using brew)

Tags: java, macos, maven

I cannot run Maven from terminal on MacOS because it says

> The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly,
>
> this environment variable is needed to run this program.

I installed Java using brew, like this:

```
% brew install java
```

Check my installation by running

```
% java --version
openjdk 21.0.1 2023-10-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Homebrew (build 21.0.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Homebrew (build 21.0.1, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I think this problem maybe caused by the method of my Java installation, but I can't find the solution on internet.

Comment: And what does `echo $JAVA_HOME` show? I can recommend https://sdkman.io/ for Java ....

Comment: @khmarbaise Thank you for your reply. `echo $JAVA_HOME` shows nothing. Does this mean I need to find the java install path and then configure the JAVA_HOME environment variables? And I will try sdkman later.

Comment: Yes that exactly means that.

Comment: `sdkman` is a wonderful tool! And it solved my problem perfectly! Thank you very much.